# Popup Modal appear behind DIV

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm integrating Bing Custom Search Engine to the website. The search result will appear in popup. Below is the integration code. When i add the code directly into the html the popup modal appear behind the div, then i add the below script inorder to bring the popup modal front and its works absolutely fine.

But when i add the code dynamically, mean the Bing integration code will be added by onclick and the popup appear behind the div as below pic. But this code $(".bcs-modal").appendTo("body"); nolonger working. I have tried almost everything none of them working.

Any suggestion..?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $(".bcs-modal").appendTo("body");  
 });
</script>
```

Bing Integration Code

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="bcs_js_snippet" class="testclass" src="https://ui.customsearch.ai/api/ux/rendering-js?customConfig=bb24718a-xxxxx&market=en-US&version=latest&q="></script>
```

Onclick Function

```
 var divtest = document.createElement("div");
 divtest.setAttribute("class", "removeclass");
divtest.innerHTML = '<form class="librarysearchform-form" action="/" onSubmit="return false;" method="post" id="librarysearchform-form-bsc" accept-charset="UTF-8"> <div><div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-keywords"> <script type="text/javascript" id="bcs_js_snippet" class="testclass" src="https://ui.customsearch.ai/api/ux/rendering-js?customConfig=xxx-96535beb4319&market=en-US&version=latest&q="><\/script></div></div><div id="edit-options" class="form-item form-type-item"> <ul class="menu"> <li class="first leaf"><a title="Clicik here to Search in INCEIF Knowledge Portal and hit Enter"> <input id="ebshost-bsc" value="ebshost" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" checked> KMC Portal</a></li> <li class="leaf"><a title="Database Search by title or category">Databases</a></li> <li class="leaf"><a title="Journal Search by title or ISSN">Journals</a></li> <li class="leaf"><a title="Course resources lists">Course resources</a></li> <li class="leaf"><a title="Digital collections">Digital collections</a></li> <li class="last leaf"><a title="Exhibitions program">and more</a></li> </ul> </div> </div></form>';
```

[image]

Comment: Possibly resolvable by adding a z-index value to the class of the PopUp

Comment: Yes already still not working